# int64 c++ debian6

Tags: c++, c, gcc

why cant i get this int64 working?
i compile with g++ -x c++ -o program source.c
it keeps starting over with -2147483648  above 2147483647 ....

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int64_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    char string [512];
    int64_t a1 = atoi((const char*) gets(string));
    int64_t limit = a1 + 99999999999

    while(a1 <= limit)
    {
        char command[10000];
        sprintf(command, "%d", a1);
        FILE* pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","wa");
        fprintf (pFile, "%s\n", command);
        fclose (pFile);

       a1= a1 + 4321;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

c

Comment: Try `int64_t limit = a1 + 99999999999LL;`

Comment: ***source.txt*** - seriously?

Comment: made that a  .c  for you ,:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should replace

```
sprintf(command, "%d", a1);
```

with

```
sprintf(command, "%lld", a1);
```

Using the wrong format specifier is undefined behaviour. AFAIK, using `%d` as the format specifier in gcc forces only 32 bits to be printed out - thus resulting in what looks like overflows in your output file.

Comment: No, using the wrong format specifier does not result in conversion. It results in undefined behavior, and can be extremely dangerous if you did something like `printf("%d%n", (long long)1, &cnt);`

Comment: @R..: From what I understand, in gcc using `%d` instead of `%lld` causes only 32 bits of the 64 bits to be printed. While technically not a conversion, it is effectively converting a 64 bit value into 32 bits. But you are right, that part of my answer is misleading. I shall update it.

Comment: @MAK, how do you know which half of the 64 bits it is printing?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: A simple test (`int64_t x=0xFFFFFFFF00000000;printf("%d\n",x);`) shows that gcc prints the lower 32 bits on my machine.

Comment: What you fail to understand is that "here's what I tested on my computer and it did this" is not a valid method of programming.

Comment: @R.. i am not sure what risk you pointed out as iam new to programming C++ but is there a method you would prefer to reach the same?

Comment: If you want to print a `long long` value, you need to use a format specifier that matches it, for example `%lld` or `%llx`. Using `%d` is simply not valid. Alternatively, you could cast the value down to a smaller type before passing it to `printf`, as in `printf("%d", (int)my_long_long_var);`

Comment: @R..: Why do you assume that I fail to understand that? I have already said I agree with you - and have even updated my answer. It is undefined behaviour. What I am saying is that the OP is perceiving an overflow because gcc is printing out only 32 of the 64 bits.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was a bit rude. Your answer looks fine and I'll give a +1 to make up for it.

Answer (score 2):

`int64_t limit = a1 + 99999999999;`

Integer constant is too large.

Comment: What do you mean? Surely there will be one of `int`, `long int`, `long long int` in which the number `99999999999` fits?

Comment: In C99, integer literals always take on an appropriate type into which they fit, but I suspect the same is not true in C++.